# Algorithm for minimal cost + maximum matching in a general graph

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I've got a dataset consisting of nodes and edges.
The nodes respresent people and the edges represent their relations, which each has a cost that's been calculated using euclidean distance.

Now I wish to match these nodes together through their respective edges, where there is only one constraint:

- Any node can only be matched with a single other node.

Now from this we know that I'm working in a general graph, where every node could theoretically be matched with any node in the dataset, as long as there is an edge between them.

What I wish to do, is find the solution with the maximum matches and the overall minimum cost.

```
Node A
Node B
Node C
Node D

- Edge 1:
Start:       End      Cost
Node A       Node B   0.5

- Edge 2:
Start:       End      Cost
Node B       Node C   1

- Edge 3:
Start:       End      Cost
Node C       Node D   0.5

- Edge 2:
Start:       End      Cost
Node D       Node A   1
```

The solution to this problem, would be the following:

- Assign Edge 1 and Edge 3, as that is the maximum amount of matches ( in this case, there's obviously only 2 solutions, but there could be tons of branching edges to other nodes)
- Edge 1 and Edge 3 is assigned, because it's the solution with maximum amount of matches and the minimum overall cost (1)

I've looked into quite a few algorithms including Hungarian, Blossom, Minimal-cost flow, but I'm uncertain which is the best for this case. Also there seems so be an awful lot of material to solving these kinds of problems in bipartial graph's, which isn't really the case in this matter.

So I ask you:

1. Which algorithm would be the best in this scenario to return the (a) maximum amount of matches and (b) with the lowest overall cost.
2. Do you know of any good material (maybe some easy-to-understand pseudocode), for your recomended algorithm? I'm not the strongest in mathematical notation.

Comment: What do you mean by maximum matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), the most suitable algorithm (there are theoretically faster ones, but they're more difficult to understand) would be Edmonds' Blossom algorithm. Unfortunately it is quite complicated, but I'll try to explain the basis as best I can.

The basic idea is to take a matching, and continually improve it (increase the number of matched nodes) by making some local changes. The key concept is an **alternating path**: a path from an unmatched node to another unmatched node, with the property that the edges alternate between being in the matching, and being outside it.

If you have an alternating path, then you can increase the size of the matching by one by flipping the state (whether or not they are in the matching) of the edges in the alternating path.

If there exists an alternating path, then the matching is not maximum (since the path gives you a way to increase the size of the matching) and conversely, you can show that if there is no alternating path, then the matching is maximum. So, to find a maximum matching, all you need to be able to do is find an alternating path.

In bipartite graphs, this is very easy to do (it can be done with DFS). In general graphs this is more complicated, and this is were Edmonds' Blossom algorithm comes in. Roughly speaking:

- Build a new graph, where there is an edge between two vertices if you can get from u to v by first traversing an edge that is in the matching, and then traversing and edge that isn't.
- In this graph, try to find a path from an unmatched vertex to a matched vertex that has an unmatched neighbor (that is, a neighbor in the original graph).

Each edge in the path you find corresponds to two edges of the original graph (namely an edge in the matching and one not in the matching), so the path translates to an alternating walk in the new graph, but this is not necessarily an alternating path (the distinction between path and walk is that a path only uses each vertex once, but a walk can use each vertex multiple times).

- If the walk is a path, you have an alternating path and are done.
- If not, then the walk uses some vertex more than once. You can remove the part of the walk between the two visits to this vertex, and you obtain a new graph (with part of the vertices removed). In this new graph you have to do the whole search again, and if you find an alternating path in the new graph you can "lift" it to an alternating path for the original graph.

Going into the details of this (crucial) last step would be a bit too much for a stackoverflow answer, but you can find more details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) and perhaps having this high-level overview helps you understand the more mathematical articles.

Implementing this from scratch will be quite challenging.

For the weighted version (with the Euclidean distance), there is an even more complicated variant of Edmonds' Algorithm that can handle weights. [Kolmogorov](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html) offers a C++ implementation and accompanying paper. This can also be used for the unweighted case, so using this implementation might be a good idea (even if it is not in java, there should be some way to interface with it).

Since your weights are based on Euclidean distances there might be a specialized algorithm for that case, but the more general version I mentioned above would also work and and implementation is available for it.

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if the weighted version is build ontop of the existing maximum matching, or will it have to be implemented directly into the existing algorithm? Would you by any chance be willing to discuss this matter through IM on whatever platform that suits you the best?